# Mapping multiple tables(same fields) to single entity - Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have **Node** table with the details of the node. Every month this nodes will be copied to new master and user can anytime change the old nodes value. So, I am planning to create the different table for each copy of the master each month. example, node_jan, node_feb, node_mar etc. I can't put all the node in one table adding month field to differential because node table has more than million records and user can create multiple copy in single month. So if use creates 10 copy in single month then that will be 10 million records in single table which will go bigger and bigger slowing down the fetching and updating data.

I am planning to use Hibernate. So, my question is, is it possible that I create one Node class entity to refer to each table(By passing the table name at run-time).

**NOTE :**

I am aware that I can use inheritance create give this table name to each inherited entity. But remember, I am creating new table at run time so that approach will not work for me.

**Question :**

1. Is it possible to use the same entity to perform CRUD operation in multiple database table?(Providing table name which need to be queried at run-time)
2. Is there any other approach that I can take to design my database other than creating table at dynamically and does not hurt the performance?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can check out hibernate's `@SecondaryTable`

Comment: I guess @SecondaryTable is used for joining table. I am not trying to join the table here. I am trying to use same Entity class to fetch the different database table having same fields. If that make sense.

Comment: That looks like the perfect use case for partitioning to me. Did you consider that option? AFAIK you will not be able to use updatable views combined with unions.

Comment: I have not though of partitioning. I will have a look into it. Meanwhile, please share any useful link for the same. Thank you.